# PhalconPHP in Docker

Tags: docker, phalcon

I'm building a docker container with PhalconPHP installed on my local machine (mac) as follows:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

...

RUN git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git /cphalcon
WORKDIR /cphalcon/build
RUN ./install
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini \
    && echo "extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/phalcon.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini

...
```

Then I build it using the following method:

```
docker build -t {registry url}/images/php72/apache/mongo:phalcon-dev -f {filename} .
```

Once built, I am able to deploy to my local machine using docker-compose and it works perfectly.

Then I will push it to my private docker registry hosted on GitLab as such:

```
docker push {registry uri}/images/php72/apache/mongo:phalcon-dev
```

But when I pull it to my staging server (cent) and deploy it using docker-compose as such:

```
docker pull {registry uri}/images/php72/apache/mongo:phalcon-dev
```

The container acts as if it lost the Phalcon install.

I can command line into the container and rebuild Phalcon  using the commands in the Dockerfile and everything works as it should.

Am I missing something in the build, push or pull command?

Any help is appreciated!

Files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libssl-dev \
        unzip \
        git

RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg make g++ \
        && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
        && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongo.ini \
    && echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongo.ini

RUN git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git /cphalcon
WORKDIR /cphalcon/build
RUN ./install
RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini \
    && echo "extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/phalcon.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-phalcon.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN echo "\n \
<Directory /var/www/html>\n \
    RewriteEngine on\n \
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d\n \
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f\n \
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/\$1 [QSA,L]\n \
</Directory>\n \
" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

**Docker-Compose file:**

```
version: "3"

networks:
    proxy:
        external: true
    site:
        external: true

services:
    db:
        container_name: {container name}
        environment:
            - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD={password}
            - MONGODB_DATABASE={database}
        image: bitnami/mongodb:latest
        networks:
            - site
        restart: "always"
        volumes:
            - ./db:/bitnami/mongodb
    www:
        container_name: {container name}
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST={hostname}
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
        image: {registry name}/images/php72/apache/mongo:phalcon-dev
        networks:
            - site
            - proxy
        restart: "always"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html
```

Comment: You have no `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command that will run PhalconPHP when you create the container from the image. It will do nothing when it's run. I think it's probably not working locally either. Do you somehow run the container and then start the process explicitly when you run it locally? Please share your `docker-compose` file.

Comment: I added both the Dockerfile and the docker compose under "Files" above. I am just using the CMD inherited from the [PHP](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/85af0c14e3f23689f0851d3164ab3b630e7f016f/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile) image

Comment: I'm no PHP developer but I don't see where Phalcon is started. The `docker-compose` file looks fine but it 'runs' both the `db` and `www` containers and assumes that both (I assume the MongoDB does) have either `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` statements to bring up the process. Your `DOCKERFILE` has `RUN` statements that look to build/install Phalcon into the image but I'd expect to see someting along the lines of `ENTRYPOINT ['/run/phalconphp']` at the end and there's nothing there.

Comment: Phalcon is a c-extension that is loaded like a module in PHP, similar to the MongoDB or MySQL module.

Comment: So it's as if when I push the image to my registry, it looses the build info for the Phalcon module. I'm looking right now to see if it might be the apt-clean section of the Dockerfile causing this problem

Answer (score 1):

I also use Phalcon with docker, my docker image is based on Debian 9 but it's work perfectly.

See my dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y \ 
    apt-transport-https \ 
    lsb-release \ 
    ca-certificates \ 
    wget \ 
    curl \ 
    nano \ 
    dialog \ 
    net-tools \ 
    openssl

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php7.1 \
    php7.1-cli \
    php7.1-fpm \
    php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-curl \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php7.1-gettext \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-fileinfo \
    php7.1-json \
    php7.1-mcrypt \
    php7.1-redis \
    php7.1-intl \
    php7.1-xml \
    php7.1-zip

RUN curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | bash
RUN apt-get install -y php7.1-phalcon

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

My entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

service nginx start
service php7.1-fpm start

tail -F -n0 /etc/hosts
```

Hoping this can help you.